How can I get coordinate from google map sharing?
On google map, randomly select a location, and there is a sharing button, and what it sharing is like a short link: https://maps.app.goo.gl/RJsxEbNCHEtMUZRR7
I have an application, and we actually need the latitude and longitude from this, is there any method ?
I have known that this short link can be redirected and expanded to a longer link, which contains coordinates, howerver:
1.I am afraid that if google map change their URL, this will no longer work
2.Seems it may trigger machine identity
Actually I can see bmw or mercedes already support the feature, refer to:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOZ2EKtIEN0&t=26s
or is there any official business cooperation? which we also take into consideration
